# csv format of dataframe from pd.concate groupby() dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Lets say I have multiple data frames that have a format of

| Id no | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 | 7 |

which I want to group the data frame by "Id" and apply an aggression then store the new values in a different dataframe such as

```
df_calc = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Mean", "Median", "Std"])
for df in dataframes:
        mean = df.groupby(["Id"]).mean()
        median = df.groupby(["Id"]).median()
        std = df.groupby(["Id"]).std()

        df_f = pd.DataFrame(
            {"Mean": [mean], "Median": [median], "Std": [std]})

df_calc = pd.concat([df_calc, df_f])
```

This is the format in which my final dataframe `df_calc` comes out as
[image]

but I would like for it to look like this
[image]

How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `agg` multiple functions then swap the column level and reorder the column:

```py
out = df.groupby('Id no').agg({'A': ['median','std','mean'],
                               'B': ['median','std','mean']})

print(out)

           A                     B
      median       std mean median       std mean
Id no
1        4.0  2.828427  4.0    4.0  4.242641  4.0
2        4.0  1.414214  4.0    5.5  0.707107  5.5
```

```py
out = out.swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(axis=1)

print(out)

      mean      median            std
         A    B      A    B         A         B
Id no
1      4.0  4.0    4.0  4.0  2.828427  4.242641
2      4.0  5.5    4.0  5.5  1.414214  0.707107
```

Comment: I had a look into `.swaplevel()` but I couldn't understand why `.swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(axis=1)` resulted in the output in terms of swapping the order of the mean, median, and std. Would you be able to provide more insight into this?

Comment: @GitGoodCodes You can look at [`pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) document. `swaplevel(0, 1, 1)` means swap the level 0 and level 1 of column. Sort index sort the multi-index like `[(mean, a), (std, a), (mean, b)]` to  `[(mean, a), (mean, b), (std, b)]`.